# Does Authorize.net Silent Post work with refunds?

Tags: authorize.net, silent-post

I am building a reporting system and need to know if I can be notified via Silent Post of a refund that is either from a recurring subscription or a one time transaction? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Silent Post works for refunds. In fact, it works for all successful transactions regardless of type.

Comment: Thanks John, so I can see now it submits a silent posts on all transactions. Thanks a lot :). PS Your blog has helped out a lot too.